# Large MapKit vector overlay - advice

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite, gis

I am building an app where I visualise a rather large dataset (~5 million polygons) evenly distributed over a geographic area.

Roughly 2000 polygons are displayed at once at the appropriate zoom level. When zoomed out, the data is simply hidden.

To speed up drawing of the polygons I've implemented an R*-tree that returns the polygons that overlap the area in question.

```
-(void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(mapRect);
    NSArray *polygons = [[Polygons sharedPolygons] polygonsInRegion:region];
    for(Polygon *p in polygons) {
        // Draw polygon
    }
}
```

The actual sorting once the polygons are loaded into memory seems solvable by fetching and storing only the polygons that the user sees into the R-tree. The user is only interested in features close by or in specific regions.

I have tried SQLite but it does not seem like the right choice in this case, considering the dataset in question quickly becomes fairly large (>1gb) and maybe SQLite isn't optimal for doing queries of features within specific regions?

What are some clever ways I can store this dataset in the bundle?
Are there any specific technologies you suggest I try out for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to load the entire 1 GB dataset into memory.

You should store the data in an [R-tree in the database](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html) so that you can make region queries directly when you load the data.